# Understanding how to avoid my question being closed

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions, closed-questions

I have a question about my Biology Stack Exchange post: [What components of an egg yolk would be likely candidates for causing dietary intolerance?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/114034/what-components-of-an-egg-yolk-would-be-likely-candidates-for-causing-dietary-in)

I am new to posting on StackExchange so, obviously I missed something. I attempted to formulate my question, not as medical advice but rather what chemical/biological processes, unique to egg yolks, cause dietary intolerance. I specifically did not ask if someone had a condition based on the facts, what someone should do about it, or what prognosis to expect. Per the standard guidance, that questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions are OK, I attempted to phrase it as such. Yet it was deemed "off topic" and the question is closed. I would like to understand why and how I can correct it, since at the heart of the question, it is not my intent to ask about medical advice, but rather what biological mechanisms are at work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It would help to reference academic papers or similar research to frame your question as a general question about a phenomenon. Basically, identify the phenomenon exists and that scientists talk about it using specific terminology.

Otherwise, if you present a list of symptoms and excluded diagnoses it looks the same as anyone trying to use this site for personal medical advice, which we won't do here.

Comment: Thank you. I will modify the question.